# Conversion of regular index formula to macro

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone explain to me how to convert the formula `INDEX($C$1:$AD$1,MATCH($AE3,$C3:$AD3,0))` to a macro? It needs to only be run when I press a button. It does not need to be recalculated frequently. A single button click should fill all the values in the same column. It is okay if the destination cells end up only containing plain text.

I have included a screenshot of my Excel sheet. I marked the formula in the image.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: you just need or am i missing something?    `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(R1C3:R1C30,MATCH(R[2]C31,R[2]C3:R[2]C30,0))"`

Comment: Might be `=INDEX(R1C3:R1C30, MATCH(RC31, RC3:RC30, 0))`

Comment: What happens to the target cells? Do your commands fill them with formulas or plain text? I would prefer plain text in fact.

Comment: on your button click, put the formula as mentioned in comments above, copy and then paste as value.